# Kibana 4: how to aggregate by hour (or minute)?

Tags: histogram, kibana-4

I want to answer the question: what time window my servers are least used?

My idea is to have a 24h histogram (with 10min buckets) with the count of requests made to my server. In other words, I want to ignore date portion in datetime aggregations.

How do I create such graph in Kibana 4?